# Why does a green product that's been color corrected (with color checker passport) look blue and how do I fix it?

Tags: color-management, product-photography, color-correction

I'm a freelancer hired to edit product photos.
The company mailed the products to me so that I can ensure that the color of the products match what they look like in real life.
I do have some experience with this through working at a home shopping television network and shooting and editing products, but I never came across this problem.

The first (left) image shows what it looks like in real life after I made adjustments to the photo. The second image (right) shows what the image looks like if I only do the color checker correction (and no other adjustments).

[image: This is closer to what it looks like it real life (After making adjustments)]
[image: This is what it looks like with color checker correction (Before making any other adjustments)]

In real life, the product is more greenish, but even using the color checker passport, it clearly looks more bluish in the computer.

I'd like to know what's causing this and how I can fix it so that when I use the color checker passport, that it more closely matches what it looks like in real life.  Adjusting the colors manually is a little difficult to be consistent with the other products of the same color.  They continue to look a little off with when comparing them side by side, so I'm hoping to find the problem so that everything can be an exact match.

Comment: What's going on in the rest of your color workflow? Are you working in RGB or CMYK? Are you shooting with the same color profile you're outputting? How are you calibrating your equipment?

Comment: @LightBender I'm not entirely sure.  They send me camera raw photos taken with a Canon 5D Mark IV.  They shoot each product with the color checker.  I use the color checker plugin in lightroom to color correct it and from there I bring it into Photoshop to clean it up.  None of the other products have this problem.  It's just with this one color.

Comment: @LightBender In Photoshop after I open to file to edit it, on top it says I'm working in RGB/16.  After I make my edits, the client ask that I export to JPEG file at 100%.  I use two Asus IPS Monitors I believe.   If you need to know anything else, to help me determine the problem let me know.

Comment: @LightBender I don't think there's been any calibrating, unless you're talking about the Color Checker, I use for every photo they send me, and I don't have access to the camera or any of their equipment.

Comment: You don't use any kind of monitor calibration workflow for your monitors?

Comment: @LightBender I thought IPS monitors came calibrated already.  But I will look to see how to calibrate it.  Is there a recommended software to use for this?

Comment: **Nothing** comes calibrated & profiled already, I'm afraid. [It can't, because the rest of your hardware is an unknown] You also need to ensure you're not changing profiles on Import… & definitely make sure your screen profile is not in your workflow - that's done automatically, don't ever set it in Photoshop. Last point, get them to send you 16-bit TIFFs, not RAWs [even though they're massive by comparison] - that puts the translation of RAW to 'portable' firmly in their court..

Comment: @Tetsujin That makes sense.  I'll do some research and check which profile I'm using.  Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Often issues with CCP arise because the Passport is too small in the image. One way to make sure this isn't the case is to take a close up of the Passport in the lighting you're going to use for your product. Balance for that and use the resulting calibration on your product images which are, presumably, taken under the same lighting conditions.

Comment: What is the source of the example images? Crops/resizes of the edited files on your computer? Phone pics of your screen displaying them? Something else?

Comment: @MichaelC I would show the entire product, but they won't allow it in my portfolio, so I did a crop in Lightroom.  They are directly from the edited photoshop file (how I think it looks in person), and from the color correct (color checker passport) camera raw file.  I exported them to jpeg and uploaded them here.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it is a monitor calibration issue. The best way to perform a monitor calibration is to use an actual hardware calibration tool. Several companies make them at a variety of price points ranging from about $100 to upwards of $1500 depending on how accurate you need to be and if it can only calibrate monitors or if you need to calibrate other hardware as well (like printers.)

X-Rite and Datacolor both have models that are a good balance of capability and affordability if all you want to manage is monitors.

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate the info.  $100 isn't bad at all, but I'll have to try and find some other way to calibrate the monitors as best as I can until I can get one.

Comment: While it is a good idea to profile your monitor, I doubt that is the (only) problem, since the bottle looks cyan/bluish on my screen.  There may be a problem with the lighting.  The color checker may not be accurate from aging or improper storage. The color checker may not have been used properly.

Comment: It's really hard to say, but it sounds like a possibility.  The color checker I think maybe looked a little old, but I'm not sure.  They use their own photographer, in a different location but from the photos, it looks like it's shot in a studio, using studio lighting.  I just want to be sure the adjustments I'm making will reflect what they look like in real life when they post it on their website.  I'm wondering if comparing the adjusted photo on my phone might be a good idea.  Thanks for your input! @xiota

Comment: The lighting used for the photograph might also be an issue. For example a low CRI or a moderate CRI that just happens to not render that particular color well. My guess is that it is trouble at the source based on the scope of the work outsourced and the unfamiliarity of the contractor with monitor calibration. That the “in house color corrected” original is off just makes me more biased towards issues at the source.

Comment: This product is in the range of colors that highlight the difference between low quality LED lights and high quality LED lights.

Comment: It's not primarily a monitor calibration issue (though anyone working on color correction needs to use a calibrated/profiled monitor) because those of us with calibrated/profiled monitors are also seeing the difference.

Comment: @bobflux  I think it does have something to do with the color.  I think it's a combination of how the color reflects and how it was lit.  I noticed when I leave the product on the table, it seems to lean more toward the bluish color, but if I hold it in my hands up close, it leans more toward green.  Also, I've uploaded the photos to my phone, and they look almost the same as they do on my monitor after I've edited them.  So I am thinking maybe it is less of a color calibration issue with the monitor, but I'm not 100% certain.